# suggesting books on Field/galois theory

Tags: reference-request, advice, book-recommendation

I have finished courses on group theory and ring theory and linear algebra and abstract algebra(inrroducton with fraleigh's book) im about to take field/galois theory this semester any  good book not too advanced introductory  i think our prof suggests joseph ROtman's galois theory. But i want more opinions.

Comment: Artin's Algebra has a chapter on Galois Theory at the end.

Comment: If you want something very concise, you can read *Emil* Artin's *Galois Theory*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[$\color{green}{\text{Howie's Galois theory (Easy)}}$](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-1-85233-986-9)

[$\color{orange}{\text{Stewart's Galois Theory (Intermediate)}}$](http://www.amazon.de/Galois-Theory-Edition-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/1584883936)

[$\color{red}{\text{Cox's Galois Theory (Hard)}}$](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118072057.html)

Answer (score 1):

A good book to check out which I would say is at an intermediate level is J.P. Escofier's "Galois Theory."